# cannot delete a shared stream table with =NULL using DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

I used `table=NULL` to remove the shared stream table but an error is thrown: "Can't assign an object other than a table or a database to a shared variable." How can I release a shared table?

Answer (score 0):

In DolphinDB, "=NULL" cannot be used to remove any shared variables.
For a standard shared table, you can use `undef("table", SHARED)` or `dropStreamTable(table)` to release the variable.
For a persisted shared table, only `dropStreamTable` can be used to drop the table and the persistent data on the disk will be deleted.